# How can I capture an HTML document fragment as an alpha-transparent PNG?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparency

I'm looking for a way of capturing a section of a web page as a transparent-backgrounded PNG. This would mean that the `transparent` background property would be truly transparent. A root level element, instead of displaying white, would create a png with a transparent background.

However, I suspect the behavior I'm looking for just isn't possible. My next guess at the problem would be to create a canvas element, and somehow draw a html fragment onto the canvas. From there, capturing a PNG is trivial.

To summarise my two questions:

1. Is there a relatively simple way of capturing an HTML document fragment as a PNG, such that a root nodes `background: transparent` property truly results in transparency?
2. If not, can I draw an HTML document fragment to a canvas element, and if so, will I get the wanted behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely what you intend to capture in #1. Do you want to capture an image of what the user is seeing? I don't think thats possible.

For 2, the ability to draw HTML elements onto Canvas has been requested by various people but there is currently no drawElement() function or anything like it. :(

You can attempt to emulate the elements in Canvas with a ton of drawing, but you certainly cannot know what kind of (say) theme the user has. So if the user has the [Hot-dog stand windows theme](http://fandewindows.com/images/windows-311-hotdog-stand-scheme.png), there is no way to change your drawing accordingly.

Comment: I want to capture a PNG, that when substituted to replace the document fragment, appears identical to the user. This would mean backgrounds 'shine through', as it were. I'm not interested in the user's UI settings. Especially if they look like [that monstrosity](http://fandewindows.com/images/windows-311-hotdog-stand-scheme.png).

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has a new experimental feature in its FF 4 beta that supports [rendering an actual HTML element as a background of another element](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/mozelement/).